# pandas get the mean len of columns that is a list in groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
df = c    l 
     A  [1,2,3]
     A  [1,2,3,4]
     B  [1]
```

I want to get the mean length (and std) of the column `l`, per group of `c`.
So here the output will be:
A : 3.5
B : 1

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
s = df['l'].str.len().groupby(df['c']).mean()
print (s)
c
A    3.5
B    1.0
Name: l, dtype: float64
```

Or with aggregate multiple functions:

```
df = df['l'].str.len().groupby(df['c']).agg(['mean','std'])
print (df)
   mean       std
c                
A   3.5  0.707107
B   1.0       NaN
```